# Connecting to my parse server returns 404

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to connect to my parse server in javascript with the following code:

```
Parse.initialize("myappid", "myclientkey"); 
Parse.serverURL = "http://myserver.com/parse";
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
POST: 404 Not found
```

When I initialize my iOS project with the **same exact** credentials, the app seems to work fine. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: `myserver` ...  is this more like `http://myserver.com/`?

Comment: yeah..sorry about that. It's the .com of my aws server.

Comment: what happens when you put that url into a web browser?  does it 404?  start with that.  make sure that you have hit it.  you should get an "unauthorized" response back, which lets you know that you are connecting.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've opened up the required ports on your EC2 AWS server. The address you list assumes port 80. Parse listens by default on port 1337.

So either configure your parse server to start on port 80 or open up port 1337 and use http://server.com:1337/parse to connect.